# Attribute Error: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'analyzer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle, tokenize

```
def generate_desc(model, tokenizer, photo, max_length):
    # seed the generation process
    in_text = 'startseq'
    # iterate over the whole length of the sequence
    for i in range(max_length):
        # integer encode input sequence
        print('seqqqqq')
        sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
        print('seqqq done')
        # pad input
        sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_length)
        print('pad seqqqq')
        # predict next word
        yhat = model.predict([photo, sequence], verbose=0)
        # convert probability to integer
        yhat = argmax(yhat)
        # map integer to word
        word = word_for_id(yhat, tokenizer)
        # stop if we cannot map the word
        if word is None:
            break
        # append as input for generating the next word
        in_text += ' ' + word
        # stop if we predict the end of the sequence
        if word == 'endseq':
            break
    return in_text
```

I have problem with this line.

`sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]`

when I call this function I get this:

```
in texts_to_sequences 
return list(self.texts_to_sequences_generator(texts))

in texts_to_sequences_generator if self.analyzer is None: 
AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'analyzer'
```

Note: **tokenizer** is **pickle** file I opened and loaded